# Android change orientation without call oncreate

Tags: android, android-orientation

I have two layouts in layout and layout-land folders. The problem is when the orientation change, it will call onCreate method. How to prevent onCreate method called?

This is what I've done. But it didn't work at all.

AndroidManifest

```
<activity android:name=".MapsActivity"
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

MapsActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    orientationChange = true;
    //reload your ScrollBars by checking the newConfig
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you not want to happen inside onCreate? I think preventing that from happening would be easier than preventing all of onCreate

Comment: Don't stop the natural result of an orientation change unless you are *absolutely* understand why you want to do this and how you are going to account for the change.  You are potentially asking for a bunch of new new problems by doing this.

Answer (score 2):

When orientation is changed it needs to load new layout with new configuration. it needs to recreate it. So, there is no way to exit this recreation.

There are some way to avoid it :

1. before activity destoryed it calls `onsaveinstancestate`. Where you can save your view state & in `onCreate` you can get the savedInstance & repopulate it.

**Save Your Activity State**

```
static final String STATE_SCORE = "playerScore";
static final String STATE_LEVEL = "playerLevel";

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Save the user's current game state
savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);

// Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

**Restore Your Activity State**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first

// Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    // Restore value of members from saved state
    mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
    mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
} else {
    // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
}
...
}
```

2. You can use Fragment. In which you need to set `setRetainIntace(true)`. Then fragment will not destroyed while activity is destroyed.

**Refs :**

[Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

Answer (score 1):

Add this in manifest file for your Activity

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use**

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

**or**

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

to lock the orientation. Because as you mentioned, the onCreate is called everytime the screen rotates.

But you have to call it before the setContentView(R.layout.main) Could look like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
setContentView(R.layout.main); 
}
```

**or**   `android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"`

like this in your **AndroidManifest**

```
<activity
            android:name=".ActivitiesClasses.Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Comment: Worked here. Thank you.

Comment: please mark as favourite answer so it will helps more people